# How to debug ASP.NET Webforms application on remote server?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have an WebForm .NET application on a remote server. I don't have access to server configuration, just to FTP (aspx and cs files). 
We migrate servers and one functionality was the hability to upload an excel file with codes and download a excel file with information about those codes. On the new server this doesn't work. Nothing happens when I upload a file, the page is refreshed but the file is not downloaded. So I don't know how to debug this. 
How can i debug this issue?

Comment: What does all this have to do with debugging? Do you have *logging* in your application? What do the logs show? Remote debugging *is* possible but you need to install the appropriate tools on the server *and* ensure you have network access to it. [This link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/remote-debugging-aspnet-on-a-remote-iis-7-5-computer) shows how to do this for VS 2017. Obviously you can't do that on a production server.

Comment: Add proper logging to your application so you *don't* have to use debugging each time there's a problem. Add tools like Glimpse to check the status of your site, past exceptions etc. Check Scott Hanselman's [If you're not using Glimpse with ASP.NET for debugging and profiling, you're missing out](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/IfYoureNotUsingGlimpseWithASPNETForDebuggingAndProfilingYoureMissingOut.aspx). There's an [extension for WebForms](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Glimpse.WebForms) too

Comment: You're not going to be able to start a remote debugging session without RDP access to the server. I'd recommend taking a look at the event logs or using logging as others have mentioned in that case.